# How to get rid of title bar in android studio

Tags: android-studio, titlebar

I am a very new programmer and I have just finished my first android app, I have a problem with the title bar. Ive googled and searched on stack overflow that if I changed the theme into **notitlebar_** i will not have a title bar. However while that is true using the xml view, it is still present on the emulator, and also present when i ran it on my phone. (I also tried android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar", but with the same results)

so how would i solve this? thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on the onCreate

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way that works best for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //hide the titlebar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```